# Laravel, Codeigniter or Zend?

Tags: java, codeigniter, laravel, zend-framework

I want to develop an ERP application. What is the best framework to use. Am good with Codeigniter and ready to learn a better framework. Plus, the application will be used in a a large organization. I have read many forums but can't end up with a concrete reason why I'd prefer one over the others.Is there an alternative programming language which is not necessarily web based? Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt your question may be treated as opinion based. although if you want to go with PHP only laravel is best framework and regarding other language you think of ruby on rails

Comment: Zend is okay for large applications and is used by many big companies, although its documentation is/was not very good (based on the last time i went near it). Laravel is quite nice and the manual is very well written and easy to follow, its easy to get setup and quite fast. CodeIgniter, the first framework I ever used, is very fast, easy to use and the manual is one of the easiest I've ever read. Unlike the others CodeIgniter does not use namespaces, although v3 does support composer autoloaders.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try laravel first as it is modern and has a lot of support. Go on the irc channel and it is a great place. zend will take a lot longer to build and plan.

if you want a proof of concept, you can get it up in a few days in laravel. then you can decide on where you want to take it from there.

Comment: I'm already learning Laravel. Thanks for the insight.